# Why won't this submenu page show? - My First WordPress Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

Starting to build my first plugin and I'm completely puzzled on why the submenu page won't show? The main page shows up, not the subpage.

I've run over the syntax what feels like a million times and I just don't see the gap on what I have here. (Page markup is complete, not shown, I'm just trying to get the menu item to show up.)

```
/* Create Menu Item */
function core_settings_menu() {

    add_menu_page(
        'Core Settings & Code Manager',
        'Core Settings',
        'manage_options',
        'core-settings-page',
        'core_settings_page_contents',
        'dashicons-superhero',
        90
    );

    add_submenu_page(
        'core-settings-page',
        'Code Snippets',
        'manage-options',
        'core-settings-code-snippets',
        'core_settings_code_snippets_markup'
    );

}

 /* Add Menu To Site */
 add_action( 'admin_menu', 'core_settings_menu' );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the thrid `menu_title` argument, and you also have a typo in the `manage-options`. Should be `manage_options`

```php
add_submenu_page(
        'core-settings-page',
        'Code Snippets',
        'Code Snippets',
        'manage_options',
        'core-settings-code-snippets',
        'core_settings_code_snippets_markup'
    );
```

[image]

Comment: You're a lifesaver, I knew it had to be something dumb. I really appreciate your time and answer!

Comment: @ClevelandWebDev no problem! Mark this answer as accepted and give it an upvote! I think it may help others in the future.